How do I create a SIGINT handler in Go which returns to the shell after SIGTSTP?
Edit: Issue appears specific to OpenBSD.
I am trying to implement a signal handler in Go which responds to SIGINT and SIGTERM.
Using the following code, I am able to use Ctrl-C to terminate the running program, but if I send SIGTSTP e.g. using Ctrl-Z it doesn't return to the shell as expected.
How can I get the expected behaviour using SIGTSTP?
package main

import (
        "os"
        "os/signal"
        "syscall"
        "time"
)

func main() {
        c := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
        signal.Notify(c, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
        go func() {
                <-c
                os.Exit(1)
        }()

        for {
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
        }
}

Observed using go1.20.1 openbsd/amd64
Scenario 1:

Invoke program
Press Ctrl-C

<Program terminates with return code 1 as expected>
Scenario 2:

Invoke program
Press Ctrl-Z

<Doesn't return to shell as expected>
Compare the above with the following program:
package main

import (
    "time"
)

func main() {
    for {
        time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}


If I run the latter program and press Ctrl-Z, it returns to the shell with something like the following:
^Z[1] + Suspended            ./test 
me@mymachine:~$ 


Why would it respond if it's stopped? It can't do anything while stopped, that's what "stopped" means.

@JimB you are right. I think what I am expecting is for the program to return control to the shell. I've edited the question.

If Ctrl-Z doesn't return to the command prompt like you expect, that's not something you can control from your program, what does it actually do? You can't handle stop signals, so I'm not sure what it is you're expecting from the Go program here.

The thing is Ctrl-Z does return to the command prompt for a handler-less program (included in a further edit).

Running your example program shows: ^Z zsh: suspended  ./test, returning to a command prompt. The same goes for bash, which shows [1]+  Stopped ./test

Thanks for running it. Please may I ask what OS you are using?

MacOS and Linux

Thanks, seems this might be OpenBSD-specific. Editing, please feel free to remove this question.

I would probably raise this on the mailing list or issue tracker, since there's nothing you can do in your code that can be solved here.

Do I understand correctly that it appears that if a Go program on OpenBSD handles SIGTERM and SIGINT, this interferes with the handling of SIGTSTP which is expected to be left intact?

Yes, that's correct. I've now reported this here: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/70548
